# Why it doesn't work, style.display

Tags: javascript

I have a short script. I want to check the visibility oder the Display of a div.
But it doesn't work. And i have no idea why, i found some other scripts with the same Code.

I didn't get the message JA

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function test()
    {
        alert('J');
        if (document.getElementById('t').style.visibility == "visible")
        {
            alert('JA');
        }
        if (document.getElementById('t').style.display == "block")
        {
            alert('JA');
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id = 't'>
    test
</div>
<input type = 'button' onClick = 'test();'>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What happens when you do `console.log(document.getElementById('t').style.visibility);`?

Comment: There are no Errors, i tried it with edge and the developer tool and with Chrome and the developer tool, i didn't get any error

Comment: @saadq: nothing happend

Comment: Yup, read the answer given by @Phil to understand why it doesn't return `"visible"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`style` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) only represents the CSS directives specified in the element's `style` attribute therefore, both `visibility` and `display` will be empty.

What you want is [computed style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

```
var t = document.getElementById('t'),
    style = window.getComputedStyle(t);

console.log('visibility', style.visibility);
console.log('display', style.display);
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ot37vtp2/1/)